# Electrons in orbitals with nodes

Tags: atoms, orbitals

Node is a region in atomic orbital where there is no possibility of finding electrons. That is no electron can be found there (region of $\psi^2 = 0$) 
Take example of say $\mathrm{2s}$ orbital: as electrons cannot be found in node, then how can it spend time in first lobe (spherical) and in second lobe (spherical) separated by nodal region where it cannot go?

And because of course it is electron and its possibility to be found that marks up possible boundary of orbital.

Comment: You're talking about [quantum tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling).

Comment: To some extent I agree that nanoputian has also asked some what same but there is no answer to above question in the post. I do not really think their being able to cross node like em wave. When em wave passes somewhere it can be found there.

Comment: Electron does not cross nodes, nor does it spend part of its time on either side. It just **is** this way, halfway here and halfway there, every moment since the beginning. Long story short, quantum chemistry is _weird_.

Comment: The electron is on one side of the node or the other only in the sense that it is more likely to be on one side than another. Crossing the node does not require ever being at the node. And being at the node has no physical meaning because you can't know position with perfect certainty by the uncertainty principle.

Comment: @PranjalRana Think about a standing wave on, say, a guitar string. There can be a node – a region of zero movement – with movement happening on both sides. That might be a better way to think about it than a ray of light propagating through space.